# How do I make these Perl regexs Python compatible?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I have these two lines in an old Perl script. When I write the Python equivalent I get all sorts of errors like valueerror: invalid `\x` escape, and stuff about encoding.

```
$line =~ s/[^\x{8}-\x{7B}]/ /ig;
$line =~ s/(Û|²|°|±|É|¹|Í)/ /g;
```

What do I need to do to get them working in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too great with Perl regex but I think I may have solved it:

```
invalid_range = re.compile(r'[^\x08-\x7B]', re.I)
invalid_unicode = re.compile(ur'(Û|²|°|±|É|¹|Í)')
line = re.sub(invalid_range , '', line)
line = re.sub(invalid_unicode, '', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

For encoding issues, if you want to put Unicode characters in your source directly, you'll need to make sure the Python interpreter knows what your file encoding is. See:

- [Python docs—Encoding Declarations](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations)
- [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)
- [PEP 3120](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/)